# How to intersect two tables without losing the duplicate values oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

How to intersect two tables without losing the duplicate values in Oracle?

TAB1:

```
A
A
B
C
```

TAB2:

```
A
A
B
D
```

Output:

```
A
A
B
```

Comment: Are those columns or rows? They look like rows but it's really hard to figure out.

Comment: I put it as column . but some how it came out wrongly

Comment: Why do you need duplicate values `A`? If you do, what happens if one table has three `A` and the other one only two or viceversa?

Comment: Add another B to table2, and adjust the result if needed.

Comment: Is a scenario where only one of the two tables has duplicates possible?

Answer (score 2):

A subquery will filter the rows:

```
select *
  from tab1
 where col in (select col from tab2)
```

Comment: Great! But I think it will not work if the `tab2` is the only table with duplicates. Maybe more info from OP about that scenario would be appreciated.

Comment: You're right. The thing is, the question is still ill defined.

Comment: Duplicate can come in both tables.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly:

```
select a.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1)
from a
intersect
select b.*, row_number() over (partition by col1 order by col1)
from b;
```

This adds a new sequential number to each row.  Intersect will go up to the matching number.

This uses `partition by col1` -- the `col1` is arbitrary.  You may need to include all columns in the `partition by`.

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . (1) My definition of complexity certainly does not match your definition.  (2) A "simple" join is not sufficient to solve this problem.

Comment: a simple join returns the output expected. If your definition of complexity is that big, maybe your code will be very nice but very tricky, which is not the best way to code. If you perform row_number over partition with intersects to do a simple join... I would review my background

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . (1) If a "simple join" returns what you think it does, then you should answer the question.  (2) What you are calling a "simple join" will multiply the results many-fold, and that doesn't seem to be the intent of the OP.  (3) There is nothing complicated about the logic in this query.  If you are not familiar with the constructs, there are many good resources around for improving your SQL skills.

Comment: select t1.c1 from tab1 t1 join (select distinct c1 from tab2) t2 on t1.c1=t2.c1. For me that's a simple join, which returns A, A, B. Sorry, I trend to simplify the code, maybe you prefer to twist it, I don't know. For me, that join is far way easier than your row_number/intersect (which I understand perfectly, but I understand as unnecessarily complicated)

Comment: Anyway, you have just to see the other response to see how you can simplify the solution (even easier than a join)...

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . That answer is not correct.  Correctness is generally preferred over "simplicity".